# Use phtml in stead of html for emails in magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, phtml, html

Im overwriting the template vendor/theme/Magento_Email/email/header.html

I want to add php in this template. Is there a way to include a template in header.phtml?
I currently have this which doesn't give an error but it doesn't load the template.
The template file is located in vendor/theme/template/email/email.phtml

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/email.phtml'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about if you create extension

In email template just use this to call header block

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="dynamic_header" template="[vendor]_[module]::[filename].phtml" area="frontend"}}
```

And in your

```
[vendor]/[module]/[frontend]/[templates]/[filename].phtml
```

You can write your dynamic html here.